# failed to upload file on internal server using php ci

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, plesk

I got an error:

> The upload path does not appear to be valid.

when trying to upload images to internal server \
I use code like this:

```
$ config ['upload_path'] = 'var / www / vhost / halalquest.id / data / admin / place /';
```

but when I try to upload to local path successfully with code like this:

```
$ config ['upload_path'] = './assets/images/product/';
```

i am new in php codeigniter so please help him
[image]
[image]

Comment: We would be happy to help but first you must include the written code here and properly format and label it. There are plenty of examples in other questions. Images don't cut it.

Answer (score 0):

Try smthing like this. 
$ config ['upload_path'] ='C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\admin.abcgencon\admin\assets\uploads'';